# retrieving previous logins using express-sessions and passport.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I am trying to display a page to the user(front-end), which shows them their login history but am a bit confused and need some help please.

Am using Express, and storing my sessions in mongoStore like this:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ 
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection 
  })
}));
```

and my login strategy is local which is located in my userController file like this:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
  successRedirect: '/',
  successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
});
```

meanwhile I have a helpers function in my handlers like this:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User  = mongoose.model('User');

const sess = passport.use(User.createStrategy()); // creates strategy during every user login

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I know that I have to create a token during each user login but i believe that is already creeated using the serialized function(in this case it's email) but then how can i keep track of the users so that during their next session, I can retrieve the date they last logged in and render(show) it to them? Authentication and login works perfect, i just need to know how I am going to display their previous logins any other future time they are signed in and click to a specific route (not homepage). thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a customized authenticate handler to store the data you need when a user successful login,

```
Router.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
        if (err) { //do something when user failed to authenticate... }
        if (!user) { //do something when user not found }

        //explicitly call req.logIn, then save related information you need
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { //do something when user failed to login }

            //for example, save the current time to user collection
            Users.updateLastLoginTime(user.id, Date.now()).then(function(){

                //when all set, send the response
                return res.json(true);
            })
        });
    })(req, res, next);
})
```

Comment: Do you have more insights in how the method '.updateLastLoginTime' on the Users schema should look like?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MarkoCen's answer, something like this will perhaps be the method in your Users model:

```
// set a time for the login
UserSchema.statics.updateLastLoginTime = function(userId, currentTime, callback) {
  User.findOne({ _id: userId }, 'lastLoginTime')
      .exec(function(error, user){
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        } else if(!userId) {
          var err = new Error('User not found.');
          err.status = 401;
          return callback(err);
        }
        user.lastLoginTime = currentTime;
      });
};
```